# Installing R 4.0.2 version

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, exit

I used to work in R 3.4.0 version. Hovewer, this version doesn't support such packages as `keras` and `tensorflow`.

I was adviced to upgrade my R version to the newest one.
I downloaded the most recent R version 4.0.2 from [the official site](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/), then ran the following code:

```r
install.packages("keras")
library(keras)
install_keras()
```

And got the following error:

```
Error in install_keras() :
You should call install_keras() only in a fresh R session that has not yet initialized Keras and TensorFlow (this is to avoid DLL in use errors during installation)
```

After this, when I tried to quit R session by `q()` , I faced the following error:

```
Error: option error has NULL value
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
Error: option error has NULL value
```

I've never faced such an error before. When I used old R version, I typed `q()` and then had to choose between `y` and `n`. No errors appeared.

I'm asking you to help to to solve this problem.

Comment: What OS are you using? Is this windows? Have you installed Anaconda 3.x for Windows already?

Comment: I use Windows 8.1. Generally I have Anaconda3 version on my PC. I installed it separately from R. When I was installing `keras` I was asked by the system, whether I would like to install so called "Miniconda 3.x". I agreed on installing this soft.

Comment: Well, yeah, something broke :-( .  Maybe make sure you aren't loading `keras` either in your startup files or by loading previous   `.Rdata` file?  and of course no initialization calls related to TensorFlow?

Comment: `tensorflow` has been downloaded successfully, as I see.
I still experience problems with installing `keras` package.

Answer (score 6):

You need to create a new environment and then you can install R 4.+ in Anaconda. Follow these steps.

```
conda create --name r4-base
```

[image]

After activating `r4-base` run these commands

```
conda activate r4-base
conda install -c conda-forge r-base
conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 r-base
```

Finally, you will notice `r-basa` version 4 will be installed.

[image]

Thereafter, you can install any supported packages. But with this only, you won't have the ability to use it in the Jupyter notebook. You need to install `install.packages('IRkernel')` and Jupyter notebook as well if you want to use it. Otherwise you are good to go with R-Studio.

For Jupyter Installation and RKernel.

```
conda install jupyter
```

Then open the R console. Write in R console

```
install.packages('IRkernel')
IRkernel::installspec()
```

Congrats! You can use Notebook for Python and R.

Answer (score 1):

Find the location of R.exe on your computer. In my computer, this executable is at

> C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin

Open another Anaconda Prompt as Administrator and change directories to wherever R.exe is on your computer with cd file path. On my computer, it’s `cd C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin`, but it might be different for you.

Then run R from within Anaconda Prompt in Admin mode with `R.exe`

You’ll notice that you’re in an R session. From here, run the following three commands into the terminal.

> 1. install.packages("devtools")
> 2. devtools::install_github("IRkernel/IRkernel")
> 3. IRkernel::installspec()

In order, they (1) install the devtools package which gets you the install_github() function, (2) install the IR Kernel from GitHub, and (3) tell Jupyter where to find the IR Kernel.

Open Jupyter notebook and enjoy your new R kernel!

Get more information [here](https://richpauloo.github.io/2018-05-16-Installing-the-R-kernel-in-Jupyter-Lab/)

Answer (score 0):

@Rheatey Bash works perfectly. but i was facing python.exe this program cant start because api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll python system error. this is a problem running on windows 7 but i resolved this issue by installing the kernel following  https://richpauloo.github.io/2018-05-16-Installing-the-R-kernel-in-Jupyter-Lab/ and it works fine